# ArrayAdapter<HashMap<,,>> with commonsguy EndlessAdapter class

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac

**How to use ArrayAdapter-HashMap- with EndlessAdapter class?**

```
  class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {
        private RotateAnimation rotate=null;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>> a=(ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>)getWrappedAdapter();

        DemoAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
        super(new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(Base.this,
                                          R.layout.row,
                                          android.R.id.text1, <------ ????
                                          items)); <------ ????
```

I have two columns in my row `R.layout.text1` and R.layout.text2.

I saw few examples with `PROJECTION_COLUMNS` and `VIEW_MAPPINGS` but don't know how to use it correctly.

Here is full code, it's working but I get something like {test2=dasdasd, test1=asdasd} in Listview (text1):

```
import com.commonsware.cwac.endless.EndlessAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Read extends ListActivity {

      EndlessAdapter x;
      SQLiteDatabase Db;    
      public Cursor c;
      Integer cx;

      String Hash;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.readmain);

        Hash = getIntent().getStringExtra("Hash");
        cx = getIntent().getIntExtra("Count", 0);

        Db = openOrCreateDatabase("/sdcard/test.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        x = new DemoAdapter(items);
        setListAdapter(x);
      }


      class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {
        private RotateAnimation rotate=null;

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>> a=(ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String,String>>)getWrappedAdapter();


          DemoAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {


          super(new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(ReadChat.this,
                                          R.layout.row,
                                          R.id.textas1,
                                          items));

          rotate=new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                      0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                                      0.5f);
          rotate.setDuration(600);
          rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
          rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        }

        @Override
        protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
          View row=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);

          View child=row.findViewById(R.id.textas1);

          child.setVisibility(View.GONE);

          child=row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
          child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          child.startAnimation(rotate);

          return(row);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
            c = Db.rawQuery("SELECT a, b FROM TableLIMIT "+a.getCount()+", 15",null);

            return(getWrappedAdapter().getCount()< cx);
        }

        @Override
        protected void appendCachedData() {

          String a;
              String b;

          if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                      do {
                           a = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("a"));
                           b = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("b"));

                           HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();                        
                               temp.put("test1", a);
                               temp.put("test2", b);                        
                               a.add(temp); 

                  } while (c.moveToNext());
                }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: check this blog http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: tried to replace arrayadapter with simpleadapter but got crash: `(super(new SimpleAdapter (
          ReadChat.this,
          items,
          R.layout.row,
                      new String[] {"test1", "test2"},
                      new int[] {R.id.text1, R.id.text2}));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems have nothing to do with `EndlessAdapter`.

First, get your code working with an `ArrayAdapter`, ignoring `EndlessAdapter` for now. This will require you to learn how to create a custom `ArrayAdapter`, as you will quickly discover that `ArrayAdapter` knows little about how to use a `HashMap<String, String>`. You will need to extend `ArrayAdapter` to your own `WhateverThisIsAdapter`, where you override `getView()` to handle pouring data from your `HashMap<String, String>` into inflated rows, properly handling your row recycling. [This free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android) will demonstrate some of this.

Then, and only then, wrap the working `ArrayAdapter` in an `EndlessAdapter`.

Also, never hard-wire paths, as `/sdcard` is wrong on most Android devices.

Comment: You code is giving stack overflow error while i have used my custom adapter